# Android: onActivityResult() between fragments is not working as expected

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is a code which takes to `Fragment B` from `Fragment A`.

```
private void gotoFragmentB() {
    FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
    fragment.setTargetFragment(this, CODE_PATTERN_AND_PIN);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

This one is the code which takes to `Fragment C` from `Fragment B`.

```
private void gotoFragmentC(String pattern) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Keys.VALUE, pattern);
    bundle.putInt(Keys.OPTION, Keys.OPTION_PIN_AND_PATTERN);
    FragmentC fragment = new FragmentC();
    fragment.setTargetFragment(this, getTargetRequestCode());
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

And finally, this code takes to `Fragment A` from `Fragment C`.

```
private void gotoFragmentA(String pin, String pattern) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Keys.VALUE, pin);
    intent.putExtra(Keys.PATTERN, pattern);
    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), RESULT_OK, intent);
    Log.i(ApplicationManager.LOG, "The request code is " + getTargetRequestCode());
    Log.i(ApplicationManager.LOG, "Sending " + pin + " and " + pattern);
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    closeSoftKeyboard();
}
```

According to the codes above, I managed to successfully pass data from `Fragment A` to `Fragment B`, and from `Fragment B` to `Fragment C` as well. But the thing is, I failed to bring data back to `Fragment A` from `Fragment C`.

In the last code snippet, I get the `Log` message as follows.

```
01-04 17:52:12.316 18694-18694/com.m I/MyAlarmApp: The request code is 103
01-04 17:52:12.326 18694-18694/com.m I/MyAlarmApp: Sending 1234 and 004-000&003-001&002-002&001-003&000-004&001-004&002-004&003-004&004-004
```

So, I believe probably it's the `onActivityResult()` method that is wrong-coded for now. Here's the one so far.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        switch(requestCode) {

            case CODE_PATTERN_AND_PIN:
                alarmPIN = data.getStringExtra(Keys.VALUE);
                pattern = data.getStringExtra(Keys.PATTERN);
                Log.i(ApplicationManager.LOG, "PIN set to " + alarmPIN);
                itemAlarmLock.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.pattern));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think fragment `B` is the one, whose `onActivityResult` would receive the result. You should probably do `getTargetFragment().getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(...)` to pass the result from `C` to `A`

Comment: getTargetRequestCode()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use **listeners**(interface) to pass information between fragments. **OnActivityResult** will be more useful in activity to activity communications.

Example: Let's say you have two fragments A,B and an activity and you need to pass data from B to A.
Then create an interface in B, and pass the data to the Main Activity. There create another interface and pass data to fragment A.

Fragment A should look like this:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity {
   public InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity;
   String data;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void updateData(String data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.data = data;
    //data is updated here which is from fragment B
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity = (InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement TextClicked");
    }

}

}
```

FragmentB should looks like this:

```
class FragmentB extends Fragment {
public InterfaceDataCommunicator interfaceDataCommunicator;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // call this inorder to send Data to interface
    interfaceDataCommunicator.updateData("data");
}

public interface InterfaceDataCommunicator {
    public void updateData(String data);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        interfaceDataCommunicator = (InterfaceDataCommunicator) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement TextClicked");
    }

}

}
```

and Main Activity should look:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements InterfaceDataCommunicator {
public InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void updateData(String data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity.updateData(data);

}

public interface InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity {
    public void updateData(String data);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try override **onActivityResult** in your activity for particular fragment

If Your Fragment's onActivityResult not working, try following code.

In You MainActivity

```html
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Fragment pFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        if (pFragment instanceof FragmentA) {
            if (pFragment != null) {
                pFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

And can use onActivityResult method in your fragment normally you would

```html
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```